# Trying to Migrate Jersey-core 1.X to Jersey 2.x Glassfish Maven

Tags: maven, jersey, glassfish, pom.xml

I need to migrate the dependency Jersey 1 to Jersey 2.
That was easy for the jersey-client and Jersey-server since the real equivalent existing for Glassfish(Jersey-client and Jersey-server).
But i can't find the equivalent for this dependency :

```
<groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
<artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
```

Anyone know how to migrate this one ? What's the equivalent in org.glassfish.jersey.core ?

Thank's to all.

Comment: Just use jersey-conainer-serrvlet. It will pull in everything you need. And if you need JSON support add jersey-media-json-jackson,

Comment: [Check out the docs](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/modules-and-dependencies.html#servlet-app-general)